# Reference a notebook's title cell contents in its stylesheet

Tags: formatting, stylesheet

In my stylesheet I have the following code:

```
Cell[StyleData["Notebook", "Printout"],
PageHeaders->
  {{Cell[
      TextData[{"", 
      CounterBox["Page"], "/", 
      CounterBox["LastPage"]}], "PageNumber"], 
    None, None}, 
   {None, None, 
    Cell[
     TextData[{"", 
     CounterBox["Page"], "/", 
     CounterBox["LastPage"]}], "PageNumber"]}}]
```

which gives a neat page numbering, but I'd also like to include the notebook title from a "Title" cell.

I can do this easily inside a regular notebook (not stylesheet) with the code:

```
title = 
  First @ 
    (Cases[
       NotebookGet @ EvaluationNotebook[], 
       Cell[name_, style : "Title", ___] :> name, 
       Infinity] /. {} -> {""});
```

How can I do this in the stylesheet? A fail-proof code (in case there's no "Title" cell would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could add an event handler to MenuCommand-Save of  the notebook to store title text in tagging rules, Dynamic + CurrentValue should work in stylesheet then. And the third(undocumented) argument of CurrentValues is the default value in case of missing entry.

Comment: That sounds good, I'll try to make it this way. Thanks!

Comment: CurrentValue works, but I can't style this text.